# Adding and Removing elements

Tags: java

I am supposed to make a professor the instructor of a course. The comment above the method also states the objective. However I am confused if on how to go about this. I am new to programming with java so I decided to check if the professor was in the course by doing a "instanceof" comparison. Am I headed in the right direction or did I miss something? Thank you!

- Near the end I added 2 other methods that I just came across, I believe that I implemented my getStudents incorrectly. The last two methods ask for adding a student and removing. I am not sure what the key-value pair would be for the student.

  public class Course implements Comparable {

  ```
  /**
   * course id (unique)
   */
  private int id;
  /**
   * course name
   */
  private String name;
  /**
   * course level
   */
  private int level;
  /**
   * professor teaching the course, null if none
   */
  private String professor;
  /**
   * students enrolled in the course (unique), empty if none
   */
  private HashSet<String> students;

  /**
   * Create a course. Initially there is no professor or student for the
   * course.
   *
   * @param id course id
   * @param name course name
   * @param level course level
   */
  public Course(int id, String name, int level) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.level = level;
      this.professor = null;
      this.students = new HashSet<>();
  }

  /**
   * Get the course id.
   *
   * @return course id
   */
  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }

  /**
   * Get the course name.
   *
   * @return course name
   */
  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  /**
   * Get the course level.
   *
   * @return course level
   */
  public int getLevel() {
      return level;
  }

  /**
   * Get the professor teaching the course.
   *
   * @return the professor, if none, null
   */
  public String getProfessor() {
      return professor;
  }

  /**
   * Get the students enrolled in the course.
   *
   * @return the students, organized by ascending hash codes. if there are no
   * students enrolled the list should be empty.
   */
  public Collection<String> getStudents() {
      return students;
  }

  /**
   * Make a professor the instructor of this course. If another professor was
   * teaching it, that information is lost.
   *
   * @param username the username of the professor
   */
  public void addProfessor(String username) {

  }
  ```

  }
  /**

  - Add a student to the course, if they are not enrolled,
  - **in constant time**.
    *
  - @param username the username of the student
  - @return whether the student was added or not
    */
    public boolean addStudent(String username) {
    //TODO
    return false;
    }

  /**

  - Remove a student from the course, if they are enrolled,
  - **in constant time**.
    *
  - @param username the username of the student to remove
  - @return true if the student was removed, false if the student was not in      the course
    */
    public boolean removeStudent(String username) {
    // TODO
    return false;
    }

Comment: The comment for the `addProfessor` method says that the previous professor would be overwritten by the new professor, so do you actually have to check if the professor was in the course already?

Comment: For the implementation of the add and remove student methods, take a look at the add and remove methods on a Set. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the instanceof keyword to check if an object is of a particular type at runtime. In this case the comment states that if a value was previously set it is just lost. That implies that you can simply set the given value as the professor without doing any checks

```
public void addProfessor(String userName) {
    professor = userName;
}
```

Comment: Would this by default remove the previous professor if there was one?

Comment: Yes it would just overwrite the previous value

Comment: Not sure if you saw the portion that I just added but could you explain how Student could be a HashSet? I am confused on what the Key-Value pairs would be.

Comment: @JanSolo the code above has the students variable as a HashSet. Sets don't have key-value pairs (that would be a map). A set is an unordered (usually, except for a few special types) collection of data. It allows for fast checks on whether or not an element is contained in the set. Each element in a set must be unique. So if you had {"Aaron Davis", "Jan Solo"} and tried to add another instance of "Jan Solo" it wouldn't change the set and return "false". Basically, what that is saying is that in the class each student has to have a unique String identifier (maybe full name, or student id, etc).

Comment: @JanSolo one thing to note: the implementation of getStudents above is incorrect. The method comments state that it should return a sorted list of students but you are returning the backing hash set. What you need to do is create an array list, add the students from the hash set into the list and sort it. Then return that sorted list. There are a number of stream and collections methods that can help do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the getter on `professor` to check if it is already set.

```
public void addProfessor(String professor) {
     if(this.getProfessor() == null || this.getProfessor().isEmpty()) {
         this.setProfessor(professor);
     }
}
```

Comment: The method comments state it doesn't matter if a value was previously set as the professor.

Comment: @AaronDavis, yes. I think that is the problem OP is facing. That's why he has it as a comment on the method.

Comment: It seems like you added an extra parameter and removed the void. Is there another way to implement this without editing the original method? Not sure if my professor was us to modify it in any way.

Comment: @JanSolo, just edited my answer to make it work with your existing `addProessor` method. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the method addProfessor -

```
public void addProfessor(String username) {
    /*
    This assignment will replace any other professor
    who are teaching of this course.
    If you assign the class variable **professor**,
    when you call getProfessor(), that will return
    username this professor.
    */
    this.professor = username;
}
```